# How can I calculate a multi-axis SCNVector4 rotation for a SCNNode?

Tags: math, transformation, scenekit

The SCNNode take a rotation using a `SCNVector4`, which has an angle (w) and a magnitude how that angle applies to each axis (x, y, z).  For example, to rotate 45 degrees around the x-axis I'd create a `SCNVector4` like this:

```
SCNVector4Make(1.0f, 0, 0, DEG2RAD(45))
```

What I'd like to do is rotate it across all three axis, for example: 45 degrees on the x-axis, 15 degrees on the y-axis and -135 degress across the z-axis.  Does anyone know the math to calculate the final `SCNVector4`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to generate an SCNVector4 for each of the rotations, and then multiply them. Note that the order of operations matters!

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/rotationMatrices.html has a pretty good writeup of the math. Any OpenGL reference that deals with rotation matrices is worth a look too.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of `rotation` property, use `eulerAngles` and specify angle for each axis

Comment: Why `eulerAngles` and not `rotation`?

Comment: @Crashalot From https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class: `rotation` = orientation, expressed as a rotation angle about an axis, `eulerAngles` = orientation, expressed as pitch, yaw, and roll angles, each in radians

Answer (score 2):

If you're not animating the rotation, it might be cleaner to just set the transform matrix directly, like:

```
node.transform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DRotate(node.transform, xAngle, 1, 0, 0), yAngle, 0, 1, 0), zAngle, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: Useless! Assigning the structure of one type to another structure of different type is incorrect even if it works. What if they will change one of these structures?

Comment: The headers say "public typealias SCNMatrix4 = CATransform3D”. If they change the structure of SCNMatrix4 all existing binaries will break. They can’t and won’t do that.

Answer (score 2):

Do you ask for rotation matrix or how to simply rotate in general? If the second is correct then for example:

```
[node runAction:[SCNAction rotateByX:0 y:M_PI z:0 duration:0]];
```