# How summarize two SCNVector4?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I want to rotate SCNNode by half pi for `Z` axis and by pi for `X` axis.
So I have:

```
let rotateByZ = SCNAction.rotate(toAxisAngle: SCNVector4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, CGFloat.pi * 0.25), duration: 0.3)
let rotateByX = SCNAction.rotate(toAxisAngle: SCNVector4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, CGFloat.pi), duration: 0.3)
```

How can I summarize two those `SCNVector4` in one `SCNVector4` which will rotate object for two axis at once?

I want to see next:

```
SCNVector4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, CGFloat.pi * 0.25) + SCNVector4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, CGFloat.pi) == SCNVector4(?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate a multi-axis SCNVector4 rotation for a SCNNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776637/how-can-i-calculate-a-multi-axis-scnvector4-rotation-for-a-scnnode)

Comment: @Paolo I saw it. But I need formula.